# Could not find the Bean defined in my xml file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am going through a RESTFul Webservice related java code and I have a webservice defined inside my controller as follows. It was written by someone else and 
I am trying to figure out few things.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateemployeestatushistory", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateemployeestatushistory
    (
        @RequestParam(value="employee_id", defaultValue="0") Integer employee_id,
        @RequestParam(value="company_id", defaultValue="0") Integer company_id,
        @RequestParam(value="new_status_id", defaultValue="0") Integer new_status_id,
        @RequestParam(value="new_review_status_id", defaultValue="0") Integer new_review_status_id,
        @RequestParam(value="changer_id", defaultValue="0") Integer changer_id,
        @RequestParam(value="emp_status_change_comment", defaultValue="") String emp_status_change_comment,
        @RequestParam(value="company_status_change_comment", defaultValue="") String company_status_change_comment
    ) 
    {


        try {


            // Get and validate the employee .
            employeeDao rpDao = context.getBean("employeeDao", employeeDaoImpl.class);
            employee employee = rpDao.findByemployeeId(employee_id);
            if (employee == null) { throw new Exception("Invalid employee "); }

            // Use the employee  status dao to 1) update the employee  and 2) add a new history record.
            employeeStatusDao rpsDao = context.getBean("employeeStatusDao", employeeStatusDaoImpl.class);
            rpsDao.updateStatus(context, changer_id, employee, emp_status_change_comment, new_status_id, company_status_change_comment, new_review_status_id);

            result.setWebServiceStatus("Updated employee_ table, Inserted employee__HISTORY record", true);

            logger.info("Status history successfully updated");

        } catch(Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();

        } 



    }
```

The above controller code is in my main project which is referencing a dependency(another project). I have an `applicationcontext.xml` defined where beans are 
defined in the following manner and based on the above code I was expecting something like this in the xml code :

```
<bean id="employeeStatusDao" class="abc.xyz.employee.orm.dao.impl.EmployeeStatusDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

`abc.xyz.employee.orm.dao.impl.EmployeeStatusDaoImpl`  is the absolute path of the package referring the java file in the dependency.I tried searching for the 
Java file inside the abc.xyz.employee.orm.dao.impl directory but couldn't find.

I am wondering if it should be the following bean that my above controller code must be referring to? Because right now, I don't see any errors after running the 
above controller code even if the Java file  `EmployeeStatusDaoImpl.java` is not present in the dependency project. I can see the `logger.info` message printing 
on the console though.

Also, for me, the code in the java file 
`EmployeeHistoryDaoImpl.java` which is referenced by the following bean makes more sense of updating the history.

But found something like this :

```
<bean id="employeeHistoryDao" class="abc.xyz.employee.orm.dao.impl.EmployeeHistoryDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Use dependency injection not lookups.... Generally when you are accessing the `ApplicationContext` step away from the keyboard and rethink generally you are using the wrong approach.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your reply. could you tell me how to do that? I am new to this.

Comment: Define fields for the collaborators and put `@Autowired` on it. Judging by the names in XML you are using interfaces, the types should match the interface not the concrete implementations.